# Подключение google maps

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps

Создаю ключ API:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В .html подключаю карту:

```
...
<div id="map"></div>
...
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDxRDQAmC7mMPkkP0S9mlbbbYZEhKTZpF0&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
...
```

В js инициализирую:

```
   var map;
    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 8
      });
    }
```

Но карта не отображается и выдает то такую ошибку:

> Google Maps API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError ...

То такую:

> Uncaught
>
> Gc {message: "initMap is not a function", name:
>   "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Gc
>   (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…AIzaSyDxRDQAmC7mMPkkP0S9mlbbbYZEhKTZpF0&callback=initMap:137:73"}

**Вопрос:** Как правильно подключать google карту (то ли ключ не правильно создаю)?

Есть ли способ подключения google карты без ключа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогла вставка `libraries=places` :

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=MyKey"></script>
```